# PostgreSQL: Return JSON from function using language plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following table with two fields:

```
create table tbl_jtest
(
cola int,
colb varchar(10)
);
```

Inserting some records:

```
insert into tbl_jtest values(1,'a');
insert into tbl_jtest values(2,'b');
insert into tbl_jtest values(3,'c');
insert into tbl_jtest values(4,'d');
```

**Function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_jtest1(pcola int) 
RETURNS json AS
$$
BEGIN
IF pcola = 1 
THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT to_json(a.cola) FROM tbl_jtest a;
ELSE
    RETURN QUERY  SELECT to_json(a.colb) FROM tbl_jtest a;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Error details**:

> ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function LINE 7: 
>   RETURN QUERY SELECT to_json(a.cola) FROM tbl_jtest a;
>            ^

I have tried the followings:

**Try 1**:

```
PERFORM to_json(a.cola) FROM tbl_jtest a;
```

**Try 2**:

```
RETURN QUERY PERFORM to_json(a.cola) FROM tbl_jtest a;
```

Comment: `RETURN (SELECT to_json(a.cola) FROM tbl_jtest a);` - what is you r goal anyway?..

Comment: Syntax-wise @VaoTsun is right, but the fact that you do not filter the `tbl_jtest` table suggests that you indeed want a `RETURNS SETOF json` function instead (like PostgreSQL suggests). If the table contains multiple rows, a `RETURNS json` function will fail (unless you use a `WHERE` and/or a `LIMIT 1` clause).

Comment: @VaoTsun, Return the output in the json format.

Comment: @pozs, Want to return only specific columns from the table which is based on the condition.

Comment: @pozs, There is also condition were I want to specify more than one columns like `cola,colb` in select statement.

Comment: @MAK please expand your question then with *all* relevant information (i.e. sample filtering, what is the logic behind it, how and when do you want to include multiple columns, sample input with expected output etc.)

Comment: @MAK if you want to return a column, you need `RETURNS SETOF` - look example in my answer?..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or are you looking for something like this?

```
create table tbl_jtest
(
cola int,
colb varchar(10),
colc varchar(10)

);

insert into tbl_jtest values(1,'a','e');
insert into tbl_jtest values(2,'b','f');
insert into tbl_jtest values(3,'c','g');
insert into tbl_jtest values(4,'d','h');


SELECT * FROM tbl_jtest;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_jtest1(pcola int) 
RETURNS table (j json) AS
$$
BEGIN
IF pcola = 1 
THEN
    RETURN QUERY  SELECT row_to_json(a) FROM (SELECT cola, colb FROM tbl_jtest) a;
ELSE
    RETURN QUERY  SELECT to_json(a) FROM (SELECT colb, colc FROM tbl_jtest) a;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Test 1

```
SELECT ufn_jtest1(1);
```

Output 1

```
    ufn_jtest1
1   {"cola":1,"colb":"a"}
2   {"cola":2,"colb":"b"}
3   {"cola":3,"colb":"c"}
4   {"cola":4,"colb":"d"}
```

Test2

```
SELECT ufn_jtest1(2);
```

Output2
    ufn_jtest1

```
1   {"colb":"a","colc":"e"}
2   {"colb":"b","colc":"f"}
3   {"colb":"c","colc":"g"}
4   {"colb":"d","colc":"h"}
```

Answer (score 3):

are loking for such?:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_jtest2(pcola int) 
RETURNS table (j json) AS
$$
BEGIN
IF pcola = 1 
THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT to_json(a.cola) FROM tbl_jtest a;
ELSE
    RETURN QUERY  SELECT to_json(a.colb) FROM tbl_jtest a;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```